# ArrayLIst<PojoClass> list.contain() is not working and return false?

Tags: java, android

This question ask many times in stackoverflow and i tried all masters answers.
But list.contain() return always false.
and also overide equal() method.

Here is my pojo class

```
public class RecentStickerPojo
{
    File stickerName;
    File folderName;

@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        RecentStickerPojo other = (RecentStickerPojo) obj;
        if (folderName != other.folderName&&stickerName!=other.stickerName)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

in activity class

```
RecentStickerPojo recentStickerPojo=new RecentStickerPojo();
recentStickerPojo.setStickerName(s1);
recentStickerPojo.setFolderName(f1);
list.contains(recentStickerPojo) // return false
```

Comment: Did you forget `list.add`? If not, please provide a MCVE.

Comment: Use `.equals()` to compare objects (your `File` objects).

Comment: no need to add , it is already within list , i just checking

Comment: means use list.equal(recentStickerPojo) instead of list.contains(recentStickerPojo)

Comment: Don't use `==` or `!=` to compare `File` objects.  Using `!=` compares object references, and not the which File the object is pointing to..  Since `folderName` and `other.folderName` are not the same object, they will always show as not equal if you use `!=`.  The correct way to compare `File` objects is `f1.getCanonicalPath().equals(f2.getCanonicalPath())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't forget to implement hashcode.
2. For strings, use equals (or !equals) and not == (or !=)
3. Also the equals' last 3 lines can be changed to:
   `return (folderName.equals(other.folderName) && stickerName.equals( other.stickerName)`;

Comment: 1.no ideas about hashcode.
2. There is no string element.
3.lets try.

Comment: @user11276659 if you override `equals` you must also override `hashCode`.

Answer (score 1):

No need to override hashcode, as List contains method will use equals method for comparing object. It seems you are comparing File objects directly which can be different. Yes, try by changing last comparison,

```
if (folderName.equals(other.folderName) && stickerName.equals(other.stickerName))
```